# JPA - dynamic query with count of total results

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my webapplication i have a table that shows data of "`UserEntity`".

Since there are many users, this table supports `pagination`.

The table contains a lot of filters that may be set by the client and submitted to the server for results.

The result contain a page of 10 users, and a count of total users in the DB.

In order for the server to generate the result for the client i execute 2(!!!) different queries:

1) query for the filtered `userEntity` by page index and limit(10)

2) query for the total users in the specific filter

My question is:

Is it possible to query for all of these in a single query instead of two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both actions cannot be made from a single query.

Using two queries is inevitable unless you want to cause a large overhead in the server by loading all your entities every time.(This is not an option)